# Asus Prime B450M-A/CSM Uefi

Tags: boot, uefi

I am a newbie in ubuntu and I want to ask a question about my motherboard with uefi bios "ASUS PRIME B450M-A / CSM" and a possible installation of the canonical operating system.  Now another operating system is installed.  I had been trying to install the Linux operating system successfully before.

I had already done this, but now I couldn't.  I want to install ubuntu again on this asus motherboard with uefi bios system.  A message appears that says something like: *** mok / boot / uefi or mok ... "serious error, missing the mok file in uefi" ***.  This happens on a black screen when you start the BIOS and try to boot from USB or DVD with Ubuntu on it.

I just want to install it with secure boot enabled, but it gives me trouble trying to use it in secure boot uefi, like all Microsoft operating systems, I disabled safe boot, but I prefer it to be enabled.  Since then I did it, with this feature enabled, I installed ubuntu with total calm and speed, it gave no problems.

I installed some keys in the BIOS with the Ubuntu operating system installer, copying these keys into the BIOS with the secure boot enabled, where it allowed me to access the installation through uefi only with the installer.  I am not sure how I did it.

That I have to do?  Or do I no longer have to do things that I don't understand?

Comment: It is unclear what is the problem.Does the system work with secure Boot disabled? So leave it disabled. And what is the OS installed?

Comment: Please copy the error messages as they appear in the terminal window, return here, and click [edit] then paste that important data into your question. It's linda vague what's happening and clarity would help greatly.Also please specify which Linux you have installed (i.e., Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.) and its version numbered.

Comment: I am trying to explain that I want to install the latest Ubuntu LTS, which I had done before without problems on my motherboard asus, but now to install it I have problems with the bios; I have os windows 10 now, and I want to install from scratch the canonical system and without dual-boot to the current operating system.

Comment: hello, regards, well, I want to inform you that I sent a screenshot.  I hope you can help me.  please.  Very grateful for the information you send me ... it will help others.